# Using LibXML in Perl to check other directories for file in XML include statement

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I am using [`XML::LibXML::Schema`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML::Schema) to load a schema. That schema has multiple include statements.

The problem is that the files it references are in a different root directory, which is also defined in my Perl code.

Is there any way to get `XML::LibXML` to check this root directory as well for the files in the include statements?

For example, assume the current working directory with the XML file is `C:\test\test2` and the XML file has the following statement:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="testFile.xsd" />
```

But the actual path for `testFile.xsd` is `C:\test\testFile.xsd`

When I verify the schema with `XML::LibXML` like this

```
my $schemaTest = XML::LibXML::Schema->new( originalXMLFile.xsd );
```

It gives an error because it was unable to find `testFile.xsd`.

Is there a way to look in other directories for `testFile.xsd`?

Comment: An example of what you are talking about would make this a better question.

Comment: @mob thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: Going down the options, I see four possible solutions The simplest would be to set `base_uri` option.

Comment: @ikegami: Did you make that work? How?

Comment: You didn't give an minimal and otherwise working demonstration of the problem, so I had nothing to test it with (which is also why I didn't post it as an answer).

Comment: Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071849/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-specify-an-xsd-schemalocation-attribute-in-visual-stu which I found within 5 seconds by googling for `schemaLocation` `path` - this is not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

XML::LibXML is based on libxml2, so you can use an [XML Catalog](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/spec.html). You will have to create a catalog file containing your entries, eg:

```
 <catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
     <uri name="foo.xsd" uri="file:///c:/yourpath/foo.xsd"/>
 </catalog>
```

Load it using   `$parser->load_catalog( $catalog_file );`

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept every access from `XML::LibXML` to the filesystem and network using [input callbacks](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/InputCallback.pod). All you have to do is to implement and register four callback functions. Have a look at the [example in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/InputCallback.pod#EXAMPLE-CALLBACKS).

In your case, you could implement an *open* handler that checks for a file in a list of directories.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems like that is only supported in the parser function of LibXML, not the schema function.

Answer (score -3):

With so very little information, the answer has to be *no*

If XML was specified to allow a search for XSD files then all hell would break loose while malformed data initiated an internet-wide search for a matching file

Since you're working with Windows I suggest that you may be able to achieve what you need with [NTFS Junction Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)

You should take a look at the [specification for XInclude](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/)